# How to get the list of databases in an analysis services using xmlaclient in c#

Tags: c#, ssas, xmla

I connected to a particular server in c# using xmlaClient object. Now i want to list out the all databases in that particaular server. 
how to implement that.
Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the discover method with the connection object.
the code snippet as follows

```
XmlaClient xmlConn = new XmlaClient();
xmlConn.Discover("DBSCHEMA_CATALOGS", "", "", out outParam, false, false, false);
```

it gives all the list of databases in a xml format. now you can retrieve databases in that xml by using the linq to xml concepts.